# Try and Except with Python request

Tags: python, try-except

If the script below is ran, it starts with all the people I would like (Example: Nick Ahmed, Alex Avila, etc). But gives me a `KeyError: 'row'` after 9 or so.

**SCRIPT**.

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

# GET TEAM ID AND STORE AS team_id
req = requests.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.team_all_season.bam?sport_code=%27mlb%27&all_star_sw=%27N%27&sort_order=name_asc&season=%272018%27') 
data = req.json()['team_all_season']['queryResults']['row']

for teams in data:
    team_id = teams['team_id']
    team = teams['name_abbrev']

    # GET PLAYER ID using team_id string and store PLAYER ID as playerId
    req1 = requests.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.roster_40.bam?team_id=' + str(team_id) + '') 
    roster = req1.json()['roster_40']['queryResults']['row']

    for info in roster:
        player = info['name_display_first_last']
        playerId = info['player_id']

        # Use playerId string to run through PECOTA BATTING PROJECTIONS
        req2 = requests.get("http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.proj_pecota_batting.bam?season='2018'&player_id='" + str(playerId) + "'") 
        info1 = req2.json()['proj_pecota_batting']['queryResults']['row']
        # KEYS 
        hr = info1['hr']
        sac = info1['sac']
        rbi = info1['rbi']
        tb = info1['tb']
        slg = info1['slg']
        bavg = info1['avg']
        bb = info1['bb']
        ops = info1['ops']
        hbp = info1['hbp']
        games = info1['g']
        d = info1['d']
        e = info1['e']
        so = info1['so']
        sf = info1['sf']
        tpa = info1['tpa']
        h = info1['h']
        cs = info1['cs']
        obp = info1['obp']
        t = info1['t']
        s = info1['s']
        r = info1['r']
        sb = info1['sb']
        sbpct = info1['sbpct']
        ab = info1['ab']
        ibb = info1['ibb']

        print(player,team,hr,sac,rbi,tb,slg,bavg,bb,ops,hbp,games,d,e,so,sf,tpa,h,cs,obp,t,s,r,sb,sbpct,ab,ibb)
```

If I add in a `try:` `except(KeyError):` It will work but skips a lot of players in the process, like the examples  I used earlier. Which does not make sense to me because if they worked before the `try` why would they not now? Copying in the edited portion only of the script below to show the `try:` `except:`.

**SCRIPT EDIT:**

```
# Use playerId string to run through PECOTA BATTING PROJECTIONS
req2 = requests.get("http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.proj_pecota_batting.bam?season='2018'&player_id='" + str(playerId) + "'") 
try:
    info1 = req2.json()['proj_pecota_batting']['queryResults']['row']
except(KeyError):
# KEYS 
    hr = info1['hr']
    sac = info1['sac']
    rbi = info1['rbi']
    tb = info1['tb']
    slg = info1['slg']
    bavg = info1['avg']
    bb = info1['bb']
    ops = info1['ops']
    hbp = info1['hbp']
    games = info1['g']
    d = info1['d']
    e = info1['e']
    so = info1['so']
    sf = info1['sf']
    tpa = info1['tpa']
    h = info1['h']
    cs = info1['cs']
    obp = info1['obp']
    t = info1['t']
    s = info1['s']
    r = info1['r']
    sb = info1['sb']
    sbpct = info1['sbpct']
    ab = info1['ab']
    ibb = info1['ibb']

    print(player,team,hr,sac,rbi,tb,slg,bavg,bb,ops,hbp,games,d,e,so,sf,tpa,h,cs,obp,t,s,r,sb,sbpct,ab,ibb)
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You put all the code that uses `info1` inside the `except KeyError:`. That's the exact opposite of what you want. You want to use `info1` if it _worked_, not if it _failed_.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want to debug something, you need to look at what the output is that failed. When you get a `KeyError`, don't just swallow it and then try to guess what went wrong. Print out the `KeyError`, and also print out the value that caused it (in this case, `req2.json()['prec_pecota_batting']['query_results']`, or maybe something larger like the whole `req2.text` or something). Then you'll know what you're dealing with.

Comment: First time writing a script with try and except and I see what i did now. I took your suggestion and did both print error and req2.text and looked at it for a bit. The `try:` something, (if there is an error) `except` it: then "move on" or `Pass` to the next request totally makes sense now. Thanks for making me figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the `try` `except` should be:

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

##outfile = open('MLB_HITTER_PICOTA_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y') + '.csv','w',newline='')
##writer = csv.writer(outfile)
##writer.writerow(["mlb_hitter","team","hr","sac","rbi","tb","slg","bavg","bb","ops","hbp","games","d","e","so","sf","tpa","h","cs","obp","t","s","r","sb","sbpct","ab","ibb"])

# GET TEAM ID AND STORE AS team_id
req = requests.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.team_all_season.bam?sport_code=%27mlb%27&all_star_sw=%27N%27&sort_order=name_asc&season=%272018%27') 
data = req.json()['team_all_season']['queryResults']['row']

for teams in data:
    team_id = teams['team_id']
    team = teams['name_abbrev']

    # GET PLAYER ID using team_id string and store PLAYER ID as playerId
    req1 = requests.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.roster_40.bam?team_id=' + str(team_id) + '') 
    roster = req1.json()['roster_40']['queryResults']['row']

    for info in roster:
        player = info['name_display_first_last']
        playerId = info['player_id']

        # Use playerId string to run through PECOTA BATTING PROJECTIONS
        req2 = requests.get("http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.proj_pecota_batting.bam?season='2018'&player_id='" + str(playerId) + "'")
##        pprint(req2.text)
        try:
            info1 = req2.json()['proj_pecota_batting']['queryResults']['row']
            hr = info1['hr']
            sac = info1['sac']
            rbi = info1['rbi']
            tb = info1['tb']
            slg = info1['slg']
            bavg = info1['avg']
            bb = info1['bb']
            ops = info1['ops']
            hbp = info1['hbp']
            games = info1['g']
            d = info1['d']
            e = info1['e']
            so = info1['so']
            sf = info1['sf']
            tpa = info1['tpa']
            h = info1['h']
            cs = info1['cs']
            obp = info1['obp']
            t = info1['t']
            s = info1['s']
            r = info1['r']
            sb = info1['sb']
            sbpct = info1['sbpct']
            ab = info1['ab']
            ibb = info1['ibb']

            print(player,team,hr,sac,rbi,tb,slg,bavg,bb,ops,hbp,games,d,e,so,sf,tpa,h,cs,obp,t,s,r,sb,sbpct,ab,ibb)

        except(KeyError):
            pass
```

`try:` something # if some part of this doesn't work

`except():` # that something not working- in my case `except(KeyError):`

`pass` # to the next something